# How do I prevent a link tag from adding extra padding below an image?

Tags: html, css

I have image wrapped in a link. The link adds extra padding in the bottom (Please see the red area in the attached image).
How can I remove it? I have tried to set the `padding: 0;` and `margin:0` and also I have tried `display:inline-block`, but it does not solve it.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://i50.tinypic.com/2poy3kl.jpg" /></a>​
```

**CSS:**

```
 a{
    background: red;
    padding: 0;
}
```

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/D6Ak8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: block;` for the `img` tag:

```
a img {
    display: block;
}
```

#### Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D6Ak8/1/

Answer (score 1):

Display Block is your solution 
**[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D6Ak8/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/D6Ak8/4/

Add `vertical-align:bottom` to your image. This way you will keep your inline display.

Answer (score 0):

try

`img{border:none;}`

...............